# Location Services in IOS, prompt

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-location, cllocationmanager

My application needs the location services to work, so therefore the user gets asked the question when the application is first run. 
If the user says 'OK' then it will run the whole application without it on, because it will continue doing its work. So the first run it doesn't really bring anything on the view controller.

When I press the go button in XCODE the second time, it works fine because the user has already authorised the use of location services to get lat/long.

Has anyone had this problem before ? Any advice ?

Comment: what is the problem then?

Comment: the problem is the first time its run, it  doesn't bring the info into the view controller, its blank. second time fine!

Comment: Did you have enabled location updates in the App? Check it under Settings of location Services in device

Comment: yes I have because you get the prompt to authorise location services.

Comment: So the first time, it prompts to allow loc services, then you press OK, and then the application runs without it on, i think its more to do with application flow. the second time around its perfect and runs fine.

Comment: Did you used `CLLocationManagerDelegate` functions?

Comment: Yup i have used the delegate function : didUpadeLocation . This method has the first thing in it that needs doing, which is sending the lat/long up to a db. So because thats not done the first time its executed this is where the problem is, can anyone advise ?

Comment: basically stuff is being done before the prompt comes up and asking 'Would x like to use Current Location' nothing should be done before that prompt comes up

Comment: Ok, then don't do anything until your didUpadeLocation doesn't return that the location has been updated and you will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

In your `viewDidLoad:`

```
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
[locationManager setDelegate:self];
[locationManager setDistanceFilter:kCLDistanceFilterNone];
[locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

Comment: yes thats the first thing in the viewdidload, then it goes to the event didUpdateLocation which receives the lat.long and goes to a db. but when you first install the app the prompt comes in to ask for authorisation, but it does things before this prompt comes on the screen. I have to run the app at least twice before the tableview and label comes in with correct data.

Comment: So you are saying that the app is fetching the coordinates before the user clicks "OK" button on the location services prompt.

Comment: No I am not, the prompt comes up and it goes to the delegate didUpdateLocation, thats fine! but other stuff that relies on the data from didUpdateLocation runs before and that what messes things up. The second time you run it, it works because it has already got your approval.

Comment: So what you are looking at, I can't understand your problem.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do, is update your view after the "didUpdateLocation" calls, and call "SetNeedsDisplay", so your view will draw itself to update.
Like so:

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{

    self.LabellLatitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",self.locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude];
    self.LabelLongitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",self.locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude];
    [self.view setNeedsDisplay];

}
```

Even better if you add a activity indicator intill the location updates.

Now, if your calling this from your "AppDelegate" class, you can use "NSNotificationCenter" to send message to your view, to update the labels, or view, or whatever you need, like so:

```
#pragma mark - locationManager:
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"UpdatedLocation" object:nil userInfo:dictionary];


}
```

And on your UIVIewController ViewDidLoad, user this to register to the notificaitons:

```
 //Adding self to notification Center:
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(updateView:) name:@"UpdatedLocation" object:nil];
```

Hope this helps